# XSL Logic for Radio Button not working as expected

Tags: html, xml, xslt, radio-button

XSL

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!--END OF PROLOGUE-->
    <!-- MATCH STATEMENT TO CAPTURE VARIABLE VALUES-->
    <xsl:template match="ECN">
   <input type="radio"
               id="Pre-Design Transfer"
               name="transfer">
               <!--value="Pre-Design Transfer">-->
            <label for="Pre-Design Transfer">Pre-Design Transfer</label>
            <xsl:if test="radiobuttons/prepost='Pre-Design Transfer'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </input>
        <input type="radio"
            name="transfer"
               value="Post-Design Transfer">
               <!--id="Post-Design Transfer"-->
              
            <label for="Post-Design Transfer">Post-Design Transfer</label>
            <xsl:if test="radiobuttons/prepost='Post-Design Transfer'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </input>
        <!--END PRE/POST TRANSFER PARAMETERS  PARAMETERS SECTION OF ECN-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='C:\Users\gedkins\Desktop\New folder\Trial.xsl'?>
<ECN>
    <radiobuttons>
        <prepost>Post-Design Transfer</prepost>
    </radiobuttons>
</ECN>
```

I am tying to get the logic for the radio buttons to see the argument in the XML file. I cannot get the radio button to be selected at XML file load. They are both unchecked. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An attribute cannot be created after you have added content, the `<label>`. Move your `xsl:if` above the `<label>`:

```
<input type="radio"
      name="transfer"
      value="Post-Design Transfer">
  <xsl:if test="radiobuttons/prepost='Post-Design Transfer'">
      <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <!--id="Post-Design Transfer"-->      
  <label for="Post-Design Transfer">Post-Design Transfer</label>
</input>
```

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes, I wasn't paying close enough attention. Bad initial answer, but issue is basically the same. You have to put the attribute before any child nodes, so move it above the label for that input element.

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm.